# Check whether one column has content while the next does not

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, if there is content in one, there needs to be content in its neighboring cell.

```
        A         B     
1 | Content1 | Content2
2 | Content1 | Content2
3 | Content1 | Content2
```

I have a working macro

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim currentCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(stMember)
Set currentCell = ws.Range("A1")

Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)
    Set nextCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 1)
        If IsEmpty(nextCell) Then
            Application.Goto currentCell
            MsgBox "Cell " + currentCell + " is empty"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Both columns A and B can be empty in the same row which is fine. I need to change my script to:

If Col A has content, and Col B has, OK

If Col A is empty, and Col B is, OK

If Col A has content, and Col B doesn't, NOT OK

```
        A         B     
1 | Content1 | Content2     OK
2 | Content1 | Content2     OK
3 | Content1 | Content2     OK
4 | Content1 | Content2     OK
5 | Content1 | Content2     OK
6 |          |              OK
7 | Content1 | Content2     OK
8 | Content1 | Content2     OK
9 | Content1 |              NOT OK
10| Content1 | Content2     OK
```

I'm not asking for the script, just an outline of a method to achieve this.

Comment: Why VBA and not a formula? `=IF(AND(B1="",A1<>""),"Not Ok","Ok")`

Comment: What about if Col A is empty and Col B has content? Is that OK or Not OK? Or does it just never occur?

Comment: That will never occur, in saying that it might due to human error, but the risk isnt high enough for needing to include that variable.

Comment: Well, it would actually make the formula a bit shorter and simpler: `=IF((A1="")=(B1=""),"OK","Not OK")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments bove, there is no need for VBA CODE. You can use

```
=IF(AND(B1="",A1<>""),"Not Ok","Ok")
```

[image]

If you really want to use VBA then you don't need to loop :) We will combine the above formula and the vba code so that we don't have to loop.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Find the last row in Col A/B
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Columns("A:B").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Enter the formula in Col C
        .Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(AND(B1="""",A1<>""""),""Not Ok"",""Ok"")"

        '~~> Convert the formula to values
        .Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Value = .Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Followup from comments. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Find the last row in Col A/B
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Columns("A:B").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If

        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 And _
            Len(Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value)) = 0 Then

                '~~> Display the message and exit
                MsgBox "Cell " & .Range("B" & i).Address & " is empty"

                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you however the reason i am using VB is that i need to run the `Application.Goto currentCell` `MsgBox "Cell " + currentCell + " is empty"` on finding empty cell, rather than print a value in a third column. I will see if i can modify this accordingly.

Comment: Yes i would like the code to stop at the first `not ok` outcome if that makes sense.

Comment: @TimWilkinson: I have updated the code. Please see the edit and let me know is that is what you want? You may have to refresh the page to see the edit

Comment: That second bit is just what i was after, changed ranges etc and works perfectly. My only query would be whether i could integrate `Application.Goto` so on an error it would take my to problem cell?
Something like `Application.Goto (Range("B" & i))` ?

Comment: @TimWilkinson: Put `Application.Goto .Range("B" & i)` after the `msgbox...`